# How can I sign a transaction with a private key using the REST API Waves?

Tags: javascript, rest, blockchain, ride, wavesplatform

How can I sign a transaction with a private key using the REST API for WavesPlatform blockchain? Please, give you provide some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to sign transactions:

1. By using a node. But that node should know private key of your address. In other words, it should be your node, because you should never and ever send your private key to anybody else.
2. By using [Waves libraries for different languages](https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/waves-api-and-sdk/client-libraries.html) (python, c#, js, java). Libraries can sign transaction with provided private key and send to the network already signed tx.